# Chosing simple exercise for home

Tags: exercise, home-exercise

Imagine following exercise.

You do walking with relatively fast temp but you are still standing on the same place.
I am talking about walking at home. Like in this image (just the original video has more advanced moves too which I want to avoid at this stage):

[image]

**If I do only this, just walking on the same place,** will this be useful for my health?

---

If not can someone recommend names of more exercises to do at home?
Like maybe a list of exercise names, say: 10 pushups, etc.
So that I can than look up name of the exercise.

My goal is not to lose weight or something.
**Just to get the minimum of physical exercise which will be beneficial for my overall health.**

Answer (score 1):

The second edition of the [Physical Activity Guidelines for Americans](https://health.gov/sites/default/files/2019-09/Physical_Activity_Guidelines_2nd_edition.pdf) suggests the following for good health.

Aerobic Activities

- 150-300 minutes of moderate intensity exercise per week.
- 75-150 minutes of vigorous intensity exercise per week.
- (One or the other. OR some equivalent combination of the two.)

Muscle Strengthening Activities

- All major muscle groups should be exercised at least twice per week. The intensity level should be moderate or greater.

**On a scale of 1 to 10, with 1 being minimal effort and 10 being all-out maximal effort, the following serves to better define the relative intensity for each exercise intensity. Moderate Intensity is equal to 5 or 6. Vigorous Intensity is equal to 7 or 8.*

---

So might that look like in practice at home? Unless you're incredibly out of shape or overweight, walking or walking in place is likely going to be categorized as "low intensity". Walking quickly might be enough to qualify as moderate intensity, but in general walking is going to be a low intensity activity. So I would recommend something else.

Here's a sample routine to consider,

Aerobic Activity (feel free to mix or match)

- MON: Power Walk/Slow jog for 30 minutes. (Moderate Intensity)
- TUE: Jumping jacks 3 sets of 5 minutes (Vigorous Intensity)
- WED: Bike ride for 30 minutes. (Moderate Intensity)
- THU: Jump rope 3 sets of 5 minutes. (Vigorous Intensity)
- FRI: Walking up stairs for 30 minutes. (Moderate Intensity)

Muscle Strengthening Activity (3 sets to failure for everything)

- TUE: Squats, Slick Floor Bridge Curls, Pushups, and Inverted Rows. (For beginners)
- THU: Squats, Slick Floor Bridge Curls, Pushups, and Inverted Rows. (For beginners)
- TUE: Split Squat Jumps, Nordic Hamstring Curls, Clapping Pushups, and Pullups. (Not beginners)
- THU: Split Squat Jumps, Nordic Hamstring Curls, Clapping Pushups, and Pullups. (Not beginners)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/kb/recommended_routine

just do that. enough for the start.

Comment: that seems overwhelming, what about this one:https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/minroutine?

Comment: u dont have to do the last 3 of Core Triplet. so its only 6 exercises. and you can do just 2 sets instead of 3.   should be 60 min workout.
ofc u can also do the minroutine

Answer (score 0):

In order to strengthen your heart and lunges you want to get your heart rate up.
It should be slightly difficult to talk. I do not think walking in place will be intense enough. I think you will have to jog in place.

Another option may be to do HIIT/circuit training. E.g.

- bodyweight squats
- push-ups
- inverted rows

Do as many as you can of each exercise quite fast before moving on to the next exercise in the circuit without any breaks. Do this circuit 3-5 times in a row every second or third day.
This way you also strengthen your upper body.
You can do the inverted rows under a dinner table or using a pull up bar mounted (low) in a door frame or using a TRX with door anchor.